# How to create nested observable arrays?

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I am developing an app using HTML5, Knockouk and Jquery.

The UI presents a list of Orders. At first it will show 5 orders, and when a user clicks on a "Show More" button, the next 5 orders will show.

When an Order is clicked, I will show all the activities that are related to that Order and I will be showing the first 10 activites and so on when the user clicks on the "More" button.

I have created a small example based on the requirements. I have created the first step, but I'm not able to create step 2. I am unsure how to create a nested observable array. I have added a sample, which is working for step but not for the second step.

```
<h1>Using Observable Arrays<br /></h1>

<div id="divActivites">
    <!-- ko foreach: Activities -->
        <div data-bind="click:$root.showDesc, attr:{'name':name,'id':id}">
            <td><span data-bind="text:name"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:id"></span></td>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <input type="button" value="Show More" data-bind="click:addData" />
</div>
<div id="divActDec" data-bind="with:selectedData ">
    <span data-bind="text:id"></span><br />
    <span data-bind="text:name"></span><br />
    <span data-bind="text:randomStringDesc()"></span>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ActivityListModel() {
      var self = this;
      var total = ko.observable();
      self.Activities = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.selectedData = ko.observable();

      total = 0;

      self.addData = function () {
          var addtoArray = 5;

          var finalVal = total + addtoArray;

          for (var i = total+1; i <= finalVal; i++) {
              self.Activities.push(
              {
                  name: randomString(),
                  id: i
              }
              )
          }

          total = finalVal;
      }

      self.showDesc = function (ActivitiesDesc) {
          $("#divActivites").hide();
          $("#divActDec").show();
          self.selectedData(ActivitiesDesc);
      }
  }

  function ActivitiesDesc(data) {
      var activitydesc = this;
      activitydesc.name = data.name;
      activitydesc.actid = data.id;
  }

  function randomString() {
      var value = "";
      var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          value += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
      }
      return value;
  }

  function randomStringDesc() {
      var value = "";
      var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
          value += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
      }
      return value;
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ActivityListModel());
</script>
```

Can someone tell me how to create ActivitiesDesc object as an observable array?

Thanks,
Jollyguy

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version of what I think you're after:

### [Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VSse/)

Firstly I nested the details section into the `foreach` block and created an observable to control it's visibility `showDesc` and the `click` binding was modified to call `toggleDesc`, which switches the visibility on or off:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Activities -->
<div data-bind="click:$root.toggleDesc, attr:{'name':name,'id':id}">
    <div>Name: <span data-bind="text:name"></span>

    </div>
    <div>Id: <span data-bind="text:id"></span>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- added this block with a visible binding -->
<div id="divActDec" data-bind="visible: showDesc" 
                    style="border: 1px solid #000;">
     <h1>Details:</h1>
     ID: <span data-bind="text:id"></span><br />
     Name: <span data-bind="text:name"></span><br />
     Desc: <span data-bind="text:randomStringDesc()"></span>

</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

In the JS, you will see a new observable per `Activity` that looks like this:

```
showDesc: ko.observable(false)
```

This is set to false by default. Then there is the method to toggle the description when you click an item:

```
self.toggleDesc = function (item) {
    item.showDesc(!item.showDesc());
}
```

**Full JS**

```
function ActivityListModel() {
    var self = this;
    var total = ko.observable();
    self.Activities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedData = ko.observable();

    total = 0;

    self.addData = function () {
        var addtoArray = 5;

        var finalVal = total + addtoArray;

        for (var i = total + 1; i <= finalVal; i++) {
            self.Activities.push({
                name: randomString(),
                id: i,
                showDesc: ko.observable(false)
            })
        }

        total = finalVal;
    }

    self.toggleDesc = function (item) {
        item.showDesc(!item.showDesc());
    }
}

function ActivitiesDesc(data) {
    var activitydesc = this;
    activitydesc.name = data.name;
    activitydesc.actid = data.id;
}

function randomString() {
    var value = "";
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        value += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
    }
    return value;
}

function randomStringDesc() {
    var value = "";
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        value += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
    }
    return value;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ActivityListModel());
```

**Update:**

I've updated the sample to nest an `observableArray` in to the top level array. I have renamed the top level array to be `Orders`, which now contains an array of `activities`:

### [Updated JS Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/5VSse/2/)

The for loop now looks like this:

```
    for (var i = total + 1; i <= finalVal; i++) {
        self.Orders.push({
            name: randomString(),
            id: i,
            showDesc: ko.observable(false),
            activities: ko.observableArray([{
                "name": "Description 1",
                "actid": 123
            }, {
                "name": "Description 2",
                "actid": 456
            }])
        })
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. in your code, when clicking on a item, showDesc is showing only 1 item, but i want to show multiple items for that item. That is where i am stumped. I will be binding the datas from database, since i am learning about knockout, i was creating a simple example.

Comment: I'll have another look later

Comment: sorry for the delay, was on a vacation. I have put a button inside the activites and I tried to add some more activites for the same order when i click on that button and i was not able to do so. Then i created an activities object and then combined both and got a working example. I still have some issues in it. For example, when i click on Order1, it's showing the activites of Order1 and then when i click on Order4, only activities for Order4 should be shown, instead both Orders activities is shown. I have created an [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4XD8/). what am i doing wrong?